# How to use HTML template from server as a prop to component?

Tags: reactjs

I am getting a HTML Template from the server and I would like to go pass this HTML as prop to component and then replace text in some parts of the template with some dynamic data I have on my end.I do not need to render this Template on my end.I have seen many posts that are using dangerouslySetInnerHtml to render the HTML content in React but I did not find this helpful.Right now my response from server looks like this. I am  stuck on how to use this HTML Template from client side.

```
{template:<html><title><table><tbody><tr>
<td style="overflow-wrap: break-word;padding:10px;font-family:arial,helvetica,sans-serif;" align="left">
</td></tr><tr><td style="overflow-wrap: break-word;padding:10px;font-family:arial,helvetica,sans-serif;" align="left">
</td></tr><tr><td style="overflow-wrap: break-word;padding:10px;font-family:arial,helvetica,sans-serif;" align="left">
</td></tr></tbody></table></title> </html>,
templateId : `1`}
```

Comment: Well, what did you try? Can you show us anything?

Comment: If you don't know how to pass data as props, you're kinda in trouble. You can pass the data like `<MyComponent myProp={serverData.template} />` - You can pass the Id too if you want using a similar method, then you'll have to use something to pick out the elements you want to replace... Does that help at all?

Answer (score 1):

Use lib [react-render-html](https://github.com/utatti/react-render-html) to render html string

```
import renderHTML from 'react-render-html';
let App = React.createClass({
  render() {
    return (
      <div className='app'>
        {renderHTML("<a class='github' href='https://github.com'><b>GitHub</b></a>")}
      </div>
    );
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I normally pass this as a data attribute and and then work with it in my js code

you can do something like this i am writing an h1 tag but you can use any tag

```
<h1 id="template-data" data-testing="your html code"></h1>
```

then I am linking to a js file at the end of the file like this

```
<script src="index.js"></script>
```

so now in the index.js file ( jquery )

```
$('template-data').data('testing')
```

or normal js

```
let templateData = document.getElementById('template-data')
templateData.getAttribute('data-testing')
```